# JSON recursive search without loop

Tags: php, api

I have a JSON response from an API with parent and child messages. I would like to match the child message with the parent message.

Sample JSON Response

```
    {
  "messages": [
    {
      "messageID": 1,
      "jobID": 1,
      "from": "BM",
      "subject": null,
      "body": "This is a Test Job Message",
      "regarding": "Job",
      "createdOnUTC": "2020-11-17T05:23:52.99",
      "parentMessageID": null,
      "createdByClientPortalLoginID": null
    },
    {
      "messageID": 3,
      "jobID": 1,
      "from": "Ben Myers",
      "subject": "re: ",
      "body": "Reply",
      "regarding": "Job",
      "createdOnUTC": "2020-12-01T12:36:49.75",
      "parentMessageID": 1,
      "createdByClientPortalLoginID": null
    },
    {
      "messageID": 4,
      "jobID": 1,
      "from": "BM",
      "subject": "Test Subject",
      "body": "Test Body",
      "regarding": "Job",
      "createdOnUTC": "2020-12-01T13:14:54.5",
      "parentMessageID": null,
      "createdByClientPortalLoginID": null
    }
  ]
}
```

My Current code (Using loop and not matching the child message to the parent). I think a recursive function would work better than this or trying to add more loops.

```
        for ($x = 0; $x <= sizeof($getsbAllmessages->messages) - 1; $x++) { //Get size of array
            

                $dateinput = $getsbAllmessages->messages[$x]->createdOnUTC;
                $messagesentdate = strtotime($dateinput);
                $messagesentdate = date('Y/m/d H:i:s', $messagesentdate);
                
                if(empty($getsbAllmessages->messages[$x]->parentMessageID)){
?>
                        
                    <li class="left clearfix">
                        <span class="chat-img pull-left">
                            <img src="https://bootdey.com/img/Content/user_3.jpg" alt="User Avatar">
                        </span>
                        <div class="chat-body clearfix">
                            <div class="header">
                                <strong class="primary-font"><?php echo $getsbAllmessages->messages[$x]->from ?></strong>
                                <small class="pull-right text-muted"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> <?php echo $messagesentdate ?></small>
                            </div>
                            <p>
                                <?php echo $getsbAllmessages->messages[$x]->body ?> 
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                <?php }else{ ?>
           
                    <li class="right clearfix">
                        <span class="chat-img pull-right">
                            <img src="https://bootdey.com/img/Content/user_1.jpg" alt="User Avatar">
                        </span>
                        <div class="chat-body clearfix">
                            <div class="header">
                                <strong class="primary-font"><?php echo $getsbAllmessages->messages[$x]->from ?></strong>
                                <small class="pull-right text-muted"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> <?php echo $messagesentdate ?></small>
                            </div>
                            <p>
                                <?php echo $getsbAllmessages->messages[$x]->body ?> 
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <?php
                }     
                
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Ben

**

### UPDATE

**

I would like to be able link first message to the replies as per image below.
[image: Example]

Comment: Recursive functions are essentially the same as iterative loops. They both do a procedure repeatedly but in a different way.

Comment: I have looked at a few examples but cannot get my head around them. They make sense for the example given but I cannot work out how to make this work for my use case..

Comment: Your input data structure appears to be “flat”, so what would you want with recursion here to begin with? And what do you actually _mean_, when you say “match” child with parent?

Comment: @Benm Yes, recursion is pretty hard to wrap your head around imo.

Comment: @CBroe I have updated my question. Sorry I find it hard to write what I am thinking!!

Comment: So one parent can have multiple children, but I assume a child can not itself have children again? (Otherwise, your image of how you want to display this, would not make that much sense to begin with.) In that case, you could simply use two nested loops - the outer one only outputs the items with parent ID null, and the inner one only those with the parent ID set to the ID of the current outer loop item.

Comment: Exactly, children cannot have children messages. I was going to use 2 loops but thought there could be a better way

Comment: @Benn Would a hierarchy of data do well ?

Comment: @nice_dev Not sure do you have an example?

Comment: @Benm I mean like a full hierarchical structure of comments and it's replies inside a new key, say `child` ? By the way, how many such entries do you have for each thread?

Comment: That sounds good could be 20 to 30 no more than 60

Answer (score 0):

So following @cbroe comment above I have it working with 2 for loops.

```
                <!-- selected chat -->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 bg-white ">
                    <div class="chat-message">
                        <ul class="chat" style="padding-left: 50px; padding-right: 50px;">
           
        <?php

for ($x = 0;$x <= sizeof($getsbAllmessages->messages) - 1;$x++)
{ //Get size of array
    

    $dateinput = $getsbAllmessages->messages[$x]->createdOnUTC;
    $messagesentdate = strtotime($dateinput);
    $messagesentdate = date('Y/m/d H:i:s', $messagesentdate);

    if (empty($getsbAllmessages->messages[$x]->parentMessageID))
    {
?>
                        
                    <li class="left clearfix">
                        <span class="chat-img pull-left">
                            <img src="https://bootdey.com/img/Content/user_3.jpg" alt="User Avatar">
                        </span>
                        <div class="chat-body clearfix">
                            <div class="header">
                                <strong class="primary-font"><?php echo $getsbAllmessages->messages[$x]->from ?></strong>
                                <small class="pull-right text-muted"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> <?php echo $messagesentdate ?></small>
                            </div>
                            <p>
                                <?php echo $getsbAllmessages->messages[$x]->body ?> 
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                <?php
        for ($z = 0;$z <= sizeof($getsbAllmessages->messages) - 1;$z++)
        { //Get size of array
            if ($getsbAllmessages->messages[$z]->parentMessageID == $getsbAllmessages->messages[$x]->messageID)
            {
?>
            
                    <li class="right clearfix">
                        <span class="chat-img pull-right">
                            <img src="https://bootdey.com/img/Content/user_1.jpg" alt="User Avatar">
                        </span>
                        <div class="chat-body clearfix">
                            <div class="header">
                                <strong class="primary-font"><?php echo $getsbAllmessages->messages[$z]->from ?></strong>
                                <small class="pull-right text-muted"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> <?php echo $messagesentdate ?></small>
                            </div>
                            <p>
                                <?php echo $getsbAllmessages->messages[$z]->body ?> 
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <?php
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Thanks

Ben